# Python xpath with xml.etree.ElementTree: multiple conditions

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, xpath

I am trying to count from an XML file all the XML nodes of the form:

```
....
<node id="0">
      <data key="d0">Attribute</data>
....
</node>
....
```

For example a file like this:

```
<graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd">

  <graph edgedefault="directed">
    <node id="0">
      <data key="d0">Attribute</data>
      <data key="d1">Foo</data>
    </node>
```

What I have tried is:

```
x = graphml_root.findall(".//"+nsfy("node")+"/["+nsfy("data")+"='Attribute']")
```

Butt his only says that the text of the XML has to be "Attribute", I want to make sure that "Attribute" is the text of the node with `key="d0"`, so I tried this:

```
x = graphml_root.findall(".//"+nsfy("node")+"/"+nsfy("data")+"[@key='d0']"+"[""'Attribute']")
```

But it returns an empty list, so I am missing something.

NOTE:
I had to write a little lambda to avoid copying the xmlnamespace all teh time:

```
nsfy = lambda x : '{http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns}'+x #to be able to read namespace tags
```

Thanks.

Comment: try to implement `//*[@key="d0" and text()="Attribute"]`

Comment: It seems like both the "and" and "text()" are not recognised. I get `SyntaxError: invalid predicate` error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing something like:

```
nodes = []
containers = graphml_root.findall('.//node/data[@key="d0"]')
for container in containers:
    if container.text == "Attribute":
        nodes.append(container)

count = len(nodes)
```

Comment: It seems like both the "and" and "text()" are not recognised. I get `SyntaxError: invalid predicate` error

Comment: @excalibur1491 Well, then there's a workaround you can do - I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, that almost worked. The correct syntax for this (not so great `xml.etree.ElementTree`) package is `container.text == "Attribute"`. With that change, it all worked out.

Comment: @excalibur1491 Great! I'll edit the post to have that syntax.

Answer (score 2):

```
from lxml import etree
f= '''
    <node id="0">
      <data key="d0" t="32">Attribute</data>
      <data key="d1">Foo</data>
    </node>'''
root = etree.XML(f)
data = root.xpath('.//*[@key="d0" and text()="Attribute"]')
print(data)
```

lxml provide the `xpath` method.and it's done.

UPDATE

read the DOC of `xml.etree`,it don't supported this syntax.[the xpath supported by xml.etree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax)
So,only you can do is find `.//*[@key="d0"]`then test it's text equal to "Attribute".

Comment: I'd rather not have to change the module I am using. My code is much bigger than just this part, and I am using import `xml.etree.ElementTree as ET` everywhere.